# Is there an "and assignment operator" for && and || for shorthand?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

To add a value and assign it back to itself, I would do this:

```
x = x + y;
```

For making that shorthand, I can use the [add assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) like this:

```
x += y;
```

Is there a shorthand like this for the && and || operator for this?:

```
x = x && y;
```

I tried the below, the results is not the same as above:

```
x &= y;
```

Comment: The result is not the same because `x &&= y` would not evaluate `y` if `x` was false, I assume. There is no short-circuiting compound operator.

Comment: Is this question just for knowledge or out of curiosity etc? Because x = x && y; itself is so short to write!

Comment: how the result is not same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the list of C# operators [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx).

> x &= y – AND assignment. AND the value of y with the value of x, store
>   the result in x, and return the new value.
>
> x |= y – OR assignment. OR the value of y with the value of x, store
>   the result in x, and return the new value.

When you say "the results is not the same,"  can you provide example values of x and y that you're testing?
I think what you're observing is the difference between logical/bitwise AND/OR (&/|) and conditional AND/OR (&&/||).  The latter will not evaluate *y* if it doesn't need to in order to figure out the value of the expression.  If the evaluation of *y* has side effects, you would notice a difference between the bitwise and conditional operators.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is not as it doesn't make too much sense.

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx), there are only the following shortand operators in C#:

```
x += y – increment
x -= y – decrement    
x *= y – multiplication assignment
x /= y – division assignment
x %= y – modulus assignment
x &= y – AND assignment
x |= y – OR assignment
x ^= y – XOR assignment
x <<= y – left-shift assignment
x >>= y – right-shift assignment
```